# How do you edit a full GNOME Panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, panel

This seems like a silly question, but I'd like to add a widget to my panel. Normally one would right click on the panel and choose the correct option in the menu, but...my panel is full and there's no empty space to click on :p.
How can I access the panel menu?

Comment: If you have a full panel, where is the new widget gonna go?

Comment: well you can access the panel even if it's full right click on a very very tiny dot on the panel next to the indicators depending on your theme it might be impossible to find but it's there.

Comment: @fluteflute: The panel is filled by the Window List, so I can still add new things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Window List is preventing you from adding anything, then either:

- close some windows or
- go to another Workspace using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd>, add the item, then change back.

Answer (score 3):

When a panel is full, you can't right click anywhere to "Add to Panel".  Perhaps this was by design, but overlooked things like dynamically resizing widgets like the Window List which fills blank space.

So when your panel is full, you have only one option - remove something (that you know how to easily re-add), then right click on the now-empty space and add what you need.

You might also want to consider right-clicking on the panel, choosing "Properties" and ticking the "Show Hide Buttons".  This will give you permanent access to the Panel properties (and "Add to Panel" menu option) regardless of how full it is.

Answer (score 0):

This may look like a silly answer, but with a full Window List on the bottom panel, I moved the Workspace Switcher a little bit aside and back (unticked "lock to panel", clicked Move, dragged) and, in between, I had panel white space to click on to any purpose.
(same with trashcan or any other; moving Show Desktop on the far left was completely shrinking the Window List)